# How to remove unnecessary symbol in the column in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

my database got some data with unnecessary symbol in front it like "[image: here]"

How do I remove the front symbol. I try to do like this but it do not work.

```
SELECT DISTINCT REPLACE(NEW,'.','')
FROM [FixedAsset Control].[dbo].[NewViewReport]
```

Can anyone help me on that.

Comment: Your "unnesessary" symbol is NOT a dot, it looks like a (non-standard) dot only. You must understand what this symbol is (what code it have), and use this knowledge while building an expression. And - SELECT query removes this symbol in output only, no t in a table content.

Answer (score 1):

**If it is just one symbol for each value returned, then you could do this**

*It seems like you have some trailing spaces, that is why RTRIM is used, or DATALENGTH() if they need to be preserved. Thanks to   @Denis Rubashkin for pointing that out.*

**Solution where the spaces are removed**

```
SELECT DISTINCT RIGHT(RTRIM(NEW),(LEN(RTRIM(NEW)) - 1))
FROM [FixedAsset Control].[dbo].[NewViewReport]; -- RTRIM takes care of the trailing spaces
```

**Solution without removing the spaces:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT RIGHT(NEW,((DATALENGTH(NEW) / 2) - 1))
FROM [FixedAsset Control].[dbo].[NewViewReport]; -- Datalength also counts spaces
```

**And if you want to update the column after you validated that the result is correct:**

```
UPDATE[FixedAsset Control].[dbo].[NewViewReport]
SET NEW = RIGHT(RTRIM(NEW),(LEN(RTRIM(NEW)) - 1));
```

Or

```
UPDATE[FixedAsset Control].[dbo].[NewViewReport]
SET NEW = RIGHT(NEW,((DATALENGTH(NEW) / 2) - 1));
```

**Testing**

```
CREATE DATABASE [FixedAsset Control]
USE [FixedAsset Control]
GO
CREATE TABLE  [dbo].[NewViewReport] ([NEW] nvarchar(255));

INSERT INTO [dbo].[NewViewReport]([NEW])
VALUES('·OUTGOING QC OFFICE');

SELECT DISTINCT RIGHT(RTRIM(NEW),(LEN(RTRIM(NEW)) - 1))
FROM [FixedAsset Control].[dbo].[NewViewReport];
```

**Result**

```
(No column name)
OUTGOING QC OFFICE
```

Comment: I wouldn't suggest you use LEN-function if it exists some chance that there are rows with final spaces.

Comment: You are right, I added RTRIM() to the solution and a soluton with DATALENGTH() if the spaces need to be preserved, thanks!

Comment: @DenisRubashkin `LEN` [Returns the number of characters of the specified string expression, excluding trailing blanks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/len-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).Thus, trailing spaces will not affect this. However, leading spaces will, so `LTRIM` may be of better use... `select len('x     '), len('        x')`

Comment: @scsimon, run "select right('yx ', len('yx ') - 1)". Do you get 'x ' as expected? I'm sure not.

Comment: Yes @DenisRubashkin I get exactly what I'd expect. The expression evaluates to `right('xy ', 2 - 1)` which is `right('xy ',1)` which is a space... also your example is flawed... since `RIGHT` doesn't return `NULL`... `select right('yx', 0)`. Again, *LEN excludes trailing blanks. If that is a problem, consider using the DATALENGTH (Transact-SQL) function which does not trim the string.* This is straight from the documentation and is repeatable.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood your previous comment. So, never mind.